# BeanDefinitionOverrideException caused by 2 @EnableJpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement custom functionality in my SpringBoot repository by following the instructions [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-method-in-all-repositories) for creating a new base repository class and adding it to the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation.
However, when I do that, I get the following error:

**Stacktrace**

> `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'myRepository' defined in com.my.service.repository.MyRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on UpperLevelJpaConfig: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [com.my.data.entity.base.BaseRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=true; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in com.my.service.repository.MyRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on UpperLevelJpaConfig] for bean 'myRepository': There is already [Root bean: class [com.my.service.repository.BaseRepositoryFactoryBean2]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in com.my.service.repository.MyRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on MyServiceApplication] bound.`

After looking [at this tutorial about the Exception type](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-definition-override-exception), I think I understand that it's trying to create my repositories twice - once from my annotation, and once from the other annotation.

Is there any way to get around this? I can't change the config file or how it is applied to my service, because it comes from higher up in the project structure.

Thanks in advance!

Edited to add some more code:

My service class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RefreshScope
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = BaseRepositoryFactoryBean2.class)
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {
      "com.my.service",
    })
public class MyServiceApplication {
}
```

The UpperLevelJpaConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {PoolDataSourceConfig.class, JpaProperties.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    bootstrapMode = BootstrapMode.LAZY,
    basePackages = "${\jpa.repositoryPackagePath:null}",
    repositoryFactoryBeanClass = BaseRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class UpperLevelJpaConfig{
}
```

Comment: You might be able to make something like this work (not certain), but it can be iffy. 

Your child service can define it's own Spring configuration and control which configs are imported from the parent project though. I.E. - don't import the config class that contains the other @EnableJPA annotation. 

You may end up having to duplicate some bean definitions, but that's likely the best way to go.

Comment: You should post the relevant part of your configuration - this is more easier to understand than describing it in word. And one can spot problems that are not in your description.

Comment: Why do not not simply remove the Annotations from `UpperLevelJpaConfig` and add the missing configuration parameters to `MyServiceApplication ` ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Instead of configuring all the repositories to use my BaseRepositoryImpl, I realized that I only needed it for one.

I was able to create the repository in a standalone method instead of with the standard JavaConfig or XmlConfiguration. I removed the `@EnableJpaRepositories` from my application class, and instead did the following in my service impl class:

```
public class EventServiceImpl implements EventService {
  private EventRepository eventRepository;
  @Autowired private EntityManager entityManager;
  
  @PostConstruct // because I need the entityManager to be autowired
  public void initializeEventRepo() {
      RepositoryFactorySupport factory = 
              new BaseRepositoryFactoryBean2<EventRepository,Event, BigInteger>(
                      EventRepository.class).createRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
      this.eventRepository = factory.getRepository(EventRepository.class);
  }
```

I then used the repository as I had before, but was able to call my new methods!